# What its __NSDictionaryM. Why NSStringFromClass don't return NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I'm getting something weird that I can't get. I'm using a thirdy-party control (https://github.com/brunow/TableKit.m) and it do:

```
+ (NSSet *)cellMappingsForObject:(id)object mappings:(NSDictionary *)mappings {
    NSString *objectStringName = NSStringFromClass([object class]);
    return [mappings objectForKey:objectStringName];
}
```

It's create a mapping based in the name of the class:

```
[TKCellMapping mappingForObjectClass:[NSMutableDictionary class] block:^(TKCellMapping *cellMapping) {
//CODE
}];
```

And it check the datasource objects against it mappings. The objects are build for me as:

```
while ([rs next]) {
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    for (NSString *fieldName in [props allKeys]) {
        //CODE                
        [dict setValue:fieldValue forKey:fieldName];
    }
    [list addObject :dict]; //<--This is the datasource. The map is against each dict
}
```

So, everywhere I'm telling it is `NSMutableDictionary`. But then this weird thing happend.

When it calls `NSStringFromClass([NSMutableDictionary class])` it say `NSMutableDictionary` but when it calls `NSStringFromClass([rowDict class])` it say `__NSDictionaryM`!

Why happend this? I check for the header of `__NSDictionaryM` and Xcode navigate to `NSMutableDictionary` (?). I can't create objects from `__NSDictionaryM`.

BTW, what I need to do for replace `NSStringFromClass` to get exactly `NSMutableDictionary`?

Answer (score 11):

It's a private subclass of `NSMutableDictionary`. It **is** an `NSMutableDictionary`. [Read more about class clusters here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ClassCluster.html)

Comment: @user529758 Will the app get rejected if we compare the class name this way (i.e. with the private subclass of NSMutableDictionary). ?
For e.g., `[@"__NSDictionaryM" isEqualToString: NSStringFromClass([obj class])]`

Answer (score 1):

i've done it with a subclass check:

```
if( [[o class] isSubclassOfClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]] ) {
  // o is at least a subclass of NSMutableDictionary
}
```